# SourceKit crashes on creating 2D array of Characters

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, character

My "board" variable keeps causing my compiler to go crazy, and I have no idea why. This class doesn't reference any other class in my project and I'm confused on why it's doing this. My main objective is to create a 2D array of Characters with the rows and columns variables defined above as the dimensions of my board. I've tried everything and it still won't work. The comments out code was my latest attempt.

```
import Foundation

class Board: NSObject {

let rows: Int = 6
let columns: Int = 7
var boardRow: [Character] = [Character].init(count: 6, repeatedValue: " ")
var boardColumn: [Character] = [Character].init(count: 7, repeatedValue: " ")
//var board: [[Character]] = [boardRow][boardColumn]

// evaluation table for checking state of board ~~ not my code
var evaluationTable = [[3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3], [4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4], [5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5], [5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5], [4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4], [3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3]]

func Board() {
    createBoard()
    displayContent()
}

func createBoard() {

    for i in 0..<rows {
        for j in 0..<columns {
            board[i][j] = " "
        }
    }
}

func displayContent() {
    print(" 1  2  3  4  5  6  7")
    for j in 0..<rows {
        for k in 0..<columns {
            print("[" + board[j][k] + "]")
        }
        print()
    }

    print("---------------------------------------------------")
}

func insert(column: Int, protagonist: Character) -> Bool {
    if (column > 6 || column < 0 || board[0][column] != " ") {
        return false
    }

    else {
        for (var i = rows-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            if (board[i][column] == " ") {
                board[i][column] = protagonist;
                break
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

func remove(column: Int) {
    for i in 0..<rows {
        if (board[i][column] != " ") {
            board[i][column] = " "
            break
        }
    }
}

func areWeDone() -> Character {
    //check for win horizontally
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row += 1) {
        for (var col=0; col<columns-3; col += 1) {
            if (board[row][col] != " " && board[row][col] == board[row][col+1] && board[row][col] == board[row][col+2] && board[row][col] == board[row][col+3]) {
                return board[row][col]
            }
        }
    }

    // My up and down checker
    for (var row = 0; row < rows-3; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                board[row][col] == board[row+1][col] &&
                board[row][col] == board[row+2][col] &&
                board[row][col] == board[row+3][col]) {
                return Character(board[row][col])
                //return board[row][col]
            }
        }
    }

    // My diagonal checker
    for (var row = 0; row < rows-3; row += 1) {
        for (var col = 0; col < columns-3; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                board[row][col] == board[row+1][col+1] &&
                board[row][col] == board[row+2][col+2] &&
                board[row][col] == board[row+3][col+3]) {
                return board[row][col]
                //return board[row][col]
            }
        }
    }

    // My diagonal checker
    for (var row = 3; row < rows; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < columns-3; col += 1) {
            if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                board[row][col] == board[row-1][col+1] &&
                board[row][col] == board[row-2][col+2] &&
                board[row][col] == board[row-3][col+3]) {
                return board[row][col]
                //return Character(board[row][col])
            }
        }
    }

    return " ";
}

func isTiePresent() -> Bool {
    for j in 0..<columns {
        if (board[0][j] == " ") {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isMoveAllowed(column: Int) -> Bool {
    if (column > 6 || column < 0 || board[0][column] != " ") {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

func analyze() -> Int {
    let utility = 128
    var sum = 0
    for i in 0..<rows {
        for j in 0..<columns {
            if (board[i][j] == "O") {
                sum += evaluationTable[i][j]
            } else if (board[i][j] == "X"){
                sum -= evaluationTable[i][j]
            }
        }
    }

    return utility + sum
}

}
```

Comment: What problem are you actually facing?

Comment: @Lagos341: On a side note, `areWeDone()` should return a `Character?` (character [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)), instead of just `Character`. This allows you to return `nil` rather than an arbitrary [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) like `" "`.

Comment: @Eiko SourceKit keeps crashing. With the code I've written I can't seem to create a 2D array of characters without having problems.

Answer (score 0):

> //var board: [[Character]] = [boardRow][boardColumn]

As I'm sure you've noticed, `[boardRow][boardColumn]` isn't valid syntax. This approach is ultimately only creating 2 Arrays, anyway.

2D arrays are actually implemented as an Array of arrays. You can see that in the type `[[Character]]` means `Array<Array<Character>>`.

Suppose you have 6 rows, and 7 rows. You would first need to make an array to hold sub arrays (rows). Each array (row) should be initialized to the values

```
var board = [[Character]](count: 6, repeatedValue: [Character](count: 7, repeatedValue: " "))
```

Note: it's very likely I've mixed up "row" and "column". You may ned to play around with it.

Comment: I'm aware it isn't valid it was just my lost for all hope lol, and I have already tried that last piece of code ^. Compiler still keeps crashing.

Comment: That's not a compiler error, that's a runtime error. You should use the debugger to step through the program and see what happens. See https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: If it's not compiler error, then why does SourceKit crash every time I write: var board = [[Character]](count: 6, repeatedValue: [Character](count: 7, repeatedValue: " ")), but when I comment it out it goes back to normal without me even hitting the Run button.

Comment: Oh, is this in a playground?

Answer (score 0):

I took the freedom to refactor all of your code (this is not standard on SO), please take the advice in the comments. There was the problem with `board` and an instance where you used `+` to concatenate a `String` with a `Character` which doesn't work.

```
// Removed NSObject superclass as there's no use for it
class Board {

    let rows: Int = 6
    let columns: Int = 7

//  var boardRow: [Character] = [Character].init(count: 6, repeatedValue: " ")    // rowArray, just 6 characters
//  var boardColumn: [Character] = [Character].init(count: 7, repeatedValue: " ") // columnArray, just 7 characters

    var board = [[Character]](count: 6, repeatedValue: [Character](count: 7, repeatedValue: " "))   // You need 6 * 7 characters

    var evaluationTable = [[3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3], [4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4], [5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5], [5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5], [4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4], [3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3]]


    init() {
        displayContent()
    }

    // Using init instead of function for initialization
//  func Board() {
//      createBoard()
//      displayContent()
//  }

    // Not needed, board is already initialized to all " "
//  func createBoard() {
//      for i in 0..<rows {
//          for j in 0..<columns {
//              board[i][j] = " "
//          }
//      }
//  }

    func displayContent() {
        print(" 1  2  3  4  5  6  7")
        for j in 0..<rows {
            for k in 0..<columns {
                print("[\(board[j][k])]")
//              print("[" + board[j][k] + "]") // Doesn't work, "+" operates on strings, not char + string
            }
            print()
        }

        print("---------------------------------------------------")
    }

    func insert(column: Int, protagonist: Character) -> Bool {
        if (column > 6 || column < 0 || board[0][column] != " ") {
            return false
        } else {
//          for (var i = rows-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) { // For loops will be removed from future versions
            for i in (0..<rows).reverse() {
                if (board[i][column] == " ") {
                    board[i][column] = protagonist
                    break
                }
            }
            // What happens if no character in this column is " "? Should still true be returned?

            return true
        }
    }

    func remove(column: Int) {
        for i in 0..<rows {
            if (board[i][column] != " ") {
                board[i][column] = " "
                break // This only removes the first row in the column where char isn't " ", you sure about that?
            }
        }
    }

    // Returning nil when no winner
    func areWeDone() -> Character? {
        //check for win horizontally
        for row in 0..<rows {
            for col in 0..<columns-3 {
                if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col+1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col+2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col+3]) {
                        return board[row][col]
                }
            }
        }

        // My up and down checker
        for row in 0..<rows-3 {
            for col in 0..<columns {
                if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row+1][col] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row+2][col] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row+3][col]) {
                        return board[row][col]
                }
            }
        }

        // My diagonal checker
        for row in 0..<rows-3 {
            for col in 0..<columns-3 {
                if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row+1][col+1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row+2][col+2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row+3][col+3]) {
                        return board[row][col]
                }
            }
        }

        // My diagonal checker
        for row in 3..<rows {
            for col in 0..<columns-3 {
                if (board[row][col] != " " &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row-1][col+1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row-2][col+2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row-3][col+3]) {
                        return board[row][col]
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    func isTiePresent() -> Bool {
        for j in 0..<columns {
            if (board[0][j] == " ") {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func isMoveAllowed(column: Int) -> Bool {
        return !(column > 6 || column < 0 || board[0][column] != " ")

        // Same as this
//      if (column > 6 || column < 0 || board[0][column] != " ") {
//          return false
//      } else {
//          return true
//      }
    }

    func analyze() -> Int {
        let utility = 128
        var sum = 0
        for i in 0..<rows {
            for j in 0..<columns {
                if (board[i][j] == "O") {
                    sum += evaluationTable[i][j]
                } else if (board[i][j] == "X"){
                    sum -= evaluationTable[i][j]
                }
            }
        }

        return utility + sum
    }

}
```